# How to install Nvidia Drivers in Manjaro 18?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia, manjaro

Today I installed the latest version of Manjaro i3 18.0.3 to my MSI GE-60PC laptop which has GeForce GTX 850M. I'm using my laptop with external Monitor (connected via HDMI). After first boot, my laptop screen and external monitor were mirrored. I wasn't able to set my display settings. Then I installed the nvidia package[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA) using pacman with the following command.

```
sudo pacman -S linux419-nvidia
```

My kernel version is;

```
Linux my-msi 4.19.28-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 10 08:32:42 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA), it says;

```
5. Reboot. The nvidia package contains a file which blacklists the nouveau module, so rebooting is necessary.
```

So, i rebooted the pc after installing nvidia drivers. After reboot, my display settings was fixed, so my monitor was extended. Although, when I run the following command;

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
0:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

It says I'm still using nouveau driver. What is the proper and correct way to install nvidia drivers? I want to install cuda and pytorch after that.

When I run nvidia-modprobe command, the following kernel log occur.

```
[ 1883.794671] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[ 1883.795017] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
[ 1883.795018] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
               NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
               NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
[ 1883.795018] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
               NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
               NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
               NVRM: again.
[ 1883.795018] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
[ 1883.795132] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 237
```

Comment: You can run `mhwd-tui` from command line or *Manjaro Settings Manager* in X/Wayland for installing and seeing status of nVidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213042
Try blacklisting the following modules and reboot:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
blacklist nv
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Answer (score -1):

You can download the NVIDIA Linux driver from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). After the download has finished, run

```
sudo init 3
```

Which will take you to multi user without a desktop environment. Now, enter your user name and password, `cd` to your NVIDIA driver directory, and then run this to install the driver:

```
sudo ./nvidia-driver-name
```

When that finishes, run:

```
sudo init 5
```

The desktop environment will appear. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: On Arch linux `$ sudo init 3` yields: "Excess arguments. "  Are you referring to the legacy SysV execution levels for runtime ??